# What jQuery plugin is being used on CKEditor's front page for their slideshow?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

As seen here: http://ckeditor.com/ Tried to find it myself, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be fuelled by this script:

http://a.cksource.com/c/2/inc/js/player.js

which is in the page source, and is not a jQuery plugin.

It does not have an associated license or any associate comments that would help identify it / signify its usage.

The assumption is that the developers wrote it themselves, so get your hands dirty :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a plugin.

http://a.cksource.com/c/2/inc/js/player.js